# Get active windows explorer URL

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, window

I want to write a program to identify the URL of active explorer window with C++. But everything I could find were the way of finding URLs of all explorers and finding the contex of active window. Could you please help me?

Getting contex of active window:

```
HWND handle = GetForegroundWindow();
```

Getting URL of all explorers:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/279108/Get-URL-Of-Current-Web-Page

Comment: You have to read about Shell COM interfaces at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774328(v=vs.85).aspx (probably, you need IShellxxx interfaces).

Comment: I searched and I found the answer. And I shared it bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get explorer contex by applying `get_HWND` on your `IWebBrowser2` for each explorer. Then compare them with active window contex to find the active explorer window and its URL.